# an error occurred while deploying file. Please refer to Genymotion logs for more information

Tags: genymotion, android-developer-api

When i tried to install an apk in genymotion by drag & drop i faced the above issue. I tried by unchecking Verify apps over USB under Developer settings & verifier_verify_adb_installs 0. But none worked. Please suggest

Comment: Have you referred that log that you mention in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Is your APK for x86 (i.e. it contains `lib/x86`)? Genymotion VDs arch is x86, not ARM.